# Woocommerce REST-API

Tags: php, woocommerce-rest-api

I work on a shop with courses (virtual product) and physical products. I need to create a report: order details by course ID (=product ID).

**Problem**: If someone orders a course and a physical product the REST API  `/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?product=**ID**` outputs all details (of course because it's in the order), but I only need courses! Each position of the order will be listed within the line_items.

How can I get the data of and order by product ID without any other details of other products when I don't know the positions ID?

Any idea?

Comment: If you don't know the position of a record in the given data set you have - then you would start looping over that data set, until you find the record you are interested in ...